# Using Keras callbacks to alter the dataset

Tags: python, keras

I want to change parts of my dataset at every epoch. As written in the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/), in order to create a callback, I need to create a class. So I started by writing

```
class AlterDataset(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self,epoch,logs={}):
        #???
```

but then I realized I have no way to access the dataset of the model. Can this be done using callbacks?

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510612/change-training-dataset-every-n-epochs-in-keras) entry, but I didn't quite understand this. I have a model architecture already in place, and I use Model, not Sequential.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a [Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/) that loads the data for your model during training. It has an `on_epoch_end` method in which you could change your data before the next epoch is started.

Rough example:

```py
class MySequence(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, batchSize): # you can add parameters here
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.xTrain = loadxData() # load your x data here
        self.yTrain = loadyData() # load your y data here

    def __len__(self):
        return self.xData.shape[0]//self.batchSize

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.xTrain[index*self.batchSize:(index+1)*self.batchSize:]

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.xTrain, self.yTrain = changeData(self.xTrain, self.yTrain) # change your data here
```

Then you can fit your model using [`fit_generator`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator).

Comment: To generate my model, I use `model=Model(...)`, I do not use `Sequential`. How do I combine the two?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Sequential`, I'll add an explanation

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. If I already use data augmentation, can I still use this method? Can you fit several generators?

Comment: I guess you could just use them inside your `Sequence`. Just use them in the `loadxData` or `__getitem__` function depending on if they give you the whole dataset at once or only parts of it.

Comment: I may need to add that I am not sure if there is an easier or better way to do this, this I just a solution I came up with for my own project, where I wanted to use a different random part of an image in each epoch.